# How to sequence an webserver like nodejs or kestrel in app-v?

Tags: webserver, virtualization, kestrel-http-server, sequencing, appv

i need to have a webserver in an app-v container.
I could not find examples how to sequence and configure a webserver with app-v.

Are there examples available for sequencing e.g. nodejs or even .net core webserver kestrel?

Thank you for the help.

Simon

Comment: Your question is too generic. Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit to improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never seen a web server packaged with app-v, but I've used app-v seldom, so I may be wrong.

Solutions like [Docker](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) are much more suitable for web apps virtualization.